# Under which condition does completeness of function basis imply the uniqueness of the expansion?

Tags: analysis

I was told a function basis if had been proven to have the completeness could imply the uniqueness of the expansion. For example, if Fourier basis
$B_{F}=\{\sin(n\pi x), \cos(n\pi x)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$
had an extra element
$\sin(1.5 \pi x)$,
something would be violated and the set $B_{F}\cup \{\sin(1.5 \pi x) \}$ would not be complete.

However, this seemed to be very wrong, and in fact, from wikipedia the concept of [overcompleteness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overcompleteness) was defined.

Does completeness of function basis imply the uniqueness of the expansion? If not then why the previous example was wrong?
Under which condition does completeness of function basis imply the uniqueness of the expansion?

Comment: Is your question on infinite-dimensional spaces or also on finite dimensional spaces? It is far simpler to explain the finite dimensional case.

Comment: @DavidRaveh infinite dimensional space, and especially on the complex plane. The element of the basis does not have to be entire.